# What does using @NonNull on a void method do?

Tags: java, lombok

What's the point in [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) annotation `@NonNull` for a method?

```
class MyClass {
    @NonNull
    void run() {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Are we check the instance of class MyClass (MyClass obj == null)?

Comment: @blank: This isn't on a parameter though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a `void` method, there's no point.

For a method with a return type, it shows that it won't return null:

```
@NonNull String foo() {
    // I promise I won't return null herre!
}
```

Judging by the [tutorial](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html#nonnull), it looks like it won't generate a check within the method to ensure that it *isn't* null, but it tells any caller that they can realistically expect a non-null value to be returned.

Comment: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/907 - Lombok developers refused to generate `null` check for return values ((

Answer (score -2):

You can use `@NonNull` on the parameter of a method or constructor to have lombok generate a null-check statement for you.

Lombok has always treated any annotation named `@NonNull` on a field as a signal to generate a null-check if lombok generates an entire method or constructor for you, via for example `@Data`. Now, however, using lombok's own `@lombok.NonNull` on a parameter results in the insertion of just the null-check statement inside your own method or constructor.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the question is about `void method` without parameters. In my opinion if we can use such annotation in mentioned case than `Lombok` has some misleading stuff here. Because it's pointless to use @NonNull here.

Comment: @user3430490 You are just plagiarising [the docs](http://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html) without giving a reference or highlighting it as a quote, and without answering the question.

Comment: ok, ok... I search here (http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~djp/JACK/) and I can sy that @NonNull is to avoid null objects at the method. Hope this can help....